# Need help to understand this C# generic class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, generics, generic-constraints

I am learning Nhibernate 3.0.  In one of the sample code examples, it creates an abstract base entity class:

```
public abstract class Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>
```

then, make the `Customer` entity inherit from the `Entity` base class:

```
public class Customer : Entity<Customer>
```

I understand it's an abstract generic class, and it is using the `where` keyword to make sure the type `T` is  `Entity<T>`, this is where I get confused.

`Customer` inherits from "`Entity<Customer>`", this "`Entity<Customer>`" takes "`Customer`" as `T`, but this `Customer` is not "`Entity<T>`".

Please help me to understand this,  I'm really confused by this generic class.

Comment: Could you put a link to your actual example, if the example is on the web somewhere? I have had a search but I can't find it. I'm having issues with this myself. Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>You said</strike>

> customer inherits from "Entity", this "Entity" takes "Customer" as T,
>   but this customer is not "Entity"

That doesn't make any sense because that's what inheritance means.  It establishes an "is a" relationship.  So in fact a `Customer` is an `Entity`

Sorry that was based on the code with the generics stripped out because it wasn't in a code block.

The same principle is still valid though.  It's just a little confusing because it looks like it's a recursive definition, but it's not.

Think of it as `Customer` inherits from `Entity`  There just happens to be methods or fields that depend on the generic parameter being itself e.g. `Customer`.  I'm not familiar with NHibernate so I don't know what the rest of `Entity<T>` looks like, but I imagine it has some methods that use it's own type as a generic parameter.

Say for instance it has a method called

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetEntities()
```

that returned a list of it's own instances.  It needs that method to return the concrete type rather than the base type.  So in the `Customer` class, that method would be

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetEntities<Customer>()
```

If it didn't have the generic parameter, it could only return `IEnumerable<Entity>`

That's just an example of how it could be used, I don't know how it's actually used.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't make any sense, cuz, I am really confused, and try to understand how it works.  Can you please correct what I said to make more sense?

Comment: @feelexit you said "`Customer` is not `Entity<T>`" but it is.  The class was declared as `public class Customer : Entity<Customer>` which means that a `Customer` ***is*** an `Entity<Customer>`.

Answer (score 1):

It will make more sense when you consider what operations the base 'Entity' class tries to perform.  I'm also not familiar with nhibernate, but I would imagine one of the methods might be something akin to a Save() method.  So any class you create that inherits from the Entity class would inherit a Save() method, keeping you from having to rewrite it for every business object you make.  However, the Base entity class has to know what type of object you are trying to save.  It could use reflection, but here it uses generics to allow you to tell it what kind of class it is that is inheriting Entity.

The thing is that when 20 different classes inherit from a base class, that base class doesn't really have any knowledge of who is using its functionality.  This is a way to let the base class know "Customer" is using its methods so that it can cater specifically to "Customer"'s needs.

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause specifies a condition that the type to be **substituted** for `T` must obey. So, if the type is `Customer`, as in `Entity<Customer>` in that second line of code, then the condition is `Customer : Entity<Customer>` ... i.e., `Customer` must be a subclass of `Entity<Customer>`, else there's a compile error. And indeed it is so declared, again in that second line of code.

Applying this to what you wrote:

> this "`Entity<Customer>`" takes "Customer" as T

Here's how I would put it: `Entity<Customer>` is an instantiation of `Entity<T>` with `Customer` substituted for `T`. `T` is just a placeholder for some type; it's a type *parameter*.

> but this customer is not "`Entity<T>`"

We could just as well write the abstract method declaration with *SomeType* instead of `T`. The condition is that, in order to instantiate `Entity<`*SomeType*`>`, *SomeType* must be a subclass of `Entity<`*SomeType*`>`. Substituting `Customer` for *SomeType*, that says that `Customer` must be a subclass of `Entity<Customer>`, and it is.

If you understand that `T` is just a *parameter*, and that `Customer` is substituted for it in the case of `Entity<Customer>`, then I don't understand why you say that 'this customer is not "`Entity<T>`"', since `Customer : Entity<Customer>` declares it to be just that (with `Customer` substituted for `T` in every occurrence in the definition of `Entity<T>`).

Answer (score 0):

Sample showing how one can use such inheritance:

```
class Creatable<T> where T:Creatable<T>, new()
{
 pulibc static T Create()
 {
   T t = new T(); // we know to call new due new() constraint
   t.FinishCreation(); // we know that T implements this method due Creatable<T> constraint
   return t;
 }
 public void SomeOtherUsefulsOperation(){};
 protected virtual void FinishCreation(){};
}

class Child:Creatable<Child>
{
 public Child(){};
 protected override void FinishCreation(){/*do something special for this type */};}
}

// somewhere else
void DoSomething<T>() where T:Creatable<T>
{ 
 T item = Creatable<T>.Create();
 item.SomeOtherUsefulOperation();
}
```